# Simulation of inverting Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

I am trying to build a circuit which is controlled from an analog input signal Vin to produce a -24V signal with >50mA output. My analog card can only produce ~10mA, therefore I generate the signal using an Op-Amp. I used the analog simulation tool from Microchip (MINDI) and the simulation result differs from my hand calculation. 
[image: Simulation of inverting opamp]

The circuit represents the standard layout of a inverting amplifier. I removed most of filter capacitors and other resistors from the design guideline. 
Building a non-inverting amplifier with the same principle gives the correct results.
Is there a bug in the calculation of the simulation or does my circuit has a significant error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to build a circuit which is controlled from an analog
>   input signal Vin to produce a -24V signal with >50mA output.

To produce -24 volts from an op-amp means that it has to have a negative power rail because an op-amp cannot conjure up any voltage that is outside the range of the power rails and, your negative rail is in fact ground (0 volts): -

[image]

The MCP6V51 is a rail-to-rail output device so, if the negative rail were (say) -25 volts you could expect -24.9 volts at best.

To produce circa 50 mA requires a more specialized op-amp because the MCP6V51 cannot normally be expected to deliver more than a few mA - it has a short circuit output current of -36 mA and, under normal load conditions, the data sheet implies about 5 mA in the table on page 4.

Comment: I used the simulation for verification of my calculation. The opamp in the circuit is one of the MCP devices supported from the MINDI tool.

Comment: I don't believe what you have said affects my answer.

Comment: My pick would be http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa192.pdf which should provide the necessary current

Comment: @v3xX I have pointed out in my answer the problem as I see it. That problem is the lack of a sufficient negative power rail and not initially the choice of op-amp. Your question is: *Is there a bug in the calculation of the simulation or does my circuit has a significant error?* and I'm saying "it's a significant error".

Comment: As per your suggestion I changed direction of the power supply. Vs+ is now GND, where Vs- is now supplied with -30V. Now the tool reports the expected values back. Thank you

Comment: The OPA192 is also unsuitable for delivering a *-24V signal with >50mA output.*

Comment: In the datasheet "differential input-voltage range to the supply rail, high output current (±65 mA)" p.1. Does this not mean I can draw 65mA regardless of the configuration

Comment: That's the short circuit current (into a zero ohm load). If you look at figure 20 it implies that the voltage dropped in the output stage when driving 50 mA is about 3 volts. You need to account for this and give your negative supply enough headroom (maybe make it -28 volts). However, on some loads you may overheat the device. If for instance you wanted to deliver 50 mA at (say) -10 volts on the output, the op-amp would be burning 0.05 x (28 - 10) watts = 0.9 watts and would go into thermal shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will read the datasheet more carefully and adjust my hardware needs

Comment: This will be a problem. Since I need to adjust the output from 0-24V in <100mV steps and make measurements (1-30min) there are a lot of cases where the device will produce >0.9W

Comment: If your load is always connected to ground (positive rail) then you can buffer the op-amp output with a BJT emitter follower and take negative feedback from the emitter (R1). Then you choose the BJT that has the appropriate thermal characteristics and copper surrounding it.

Comment: I will address my follow up questions in a new thread, since my original question was answered

Comment: Please send me a link when you raise the new question @v3xX

Comment: follow up: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478106/limit-the-current-draw-from-op-amp