# Power dissipation BJT transistor as voltage follower

Tags: transistors, power-dissipation, loss

Following the discussion from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478106/limit-the-current-draw-from-op-amp/478115#478115) thread I am finalizing my calculations. I am not sure that I am calculating the power dissipation correctly. Given the following circuit
[image: powerdiss]

I need to operate the opamp between 0-2.4V in 100mV steps, sometimes holding the values for 30min. With `V_cc=3V` and `V_Bas=1V`, `V_Emit=0.5V`. The collectorcurrent reads `I_c=0.13mA` and `I_emit=0.043mA`. At this conditions the Power loss calculates as

> P_loss = (V_cc-V_Emit)*(I_c-I_emit)

I draw the power loss with the above formula over the range of `V_in`

[image: power loss]

Can I choose the right transistor based on this calculation (max ~430uW)?

Comment: Without getting bogged down in details, are you asking if finding a transistor that that dissipate a maximum of \$430\:\mu\text{W}\$ is hard to find? If so, the answer is "no, they are easy to find -- as the worst case is probably a TO-92 with about 200 C per watt or an increase of less than a tenth of one degree Celsius. It will be very hard to find a device with a problem with this dissipation -- and I'd love to hear about it, if you find one.

Comment: My main concern is if my calculation is correct

Comment: Oh. Well power dissipation will be \$\approx V_\text{CE}\cdot I_\text{C}\$ when not saturated. Can you work out those details?

Comment: With Vce=Vcc-Ve?

Comment: No, \$V_\text{CE}=V_\text{C}-V_\text{E}\$. But since (I think) \$V_\text{C}=V_\text{CC}\$ in this case (as I quickly see it) then perhaps so.

Comment: Yes. Vcc is connected to the collector of the transistor and the power supply Vs- of the opamp

Comment: Then there's your answer. The power you computed is probably wrong (if I'm reading it correctly.) It's more like the base current times the collector-emitter voltage, rather than the collector/emitter current times that voltage.

Comment: That would mean $V_{CE}\cdot I_C = P_{trans}$ the power the load draws through the transistor

Comment: No. The power is the load current times \$V_\text{CC}\$. This is divided between the load itself and the BJT, each taking up some portion.

Comment: $$V_{CC} * I_C = P_{tot}$$ . Which consists of the Power loss and the Power for the load. Correct?

Comment: If I follow you correctly, then yes. The power supply is providing a current that goes though the BJT and the load. Each have a voltage across them that is a portion of the total voltage. Their power dissipations are proportionate and they sum to the total. There is an additional portion due to the base current though the BE junction. But if not saturated, this is usually negligible.

Comment: Thank you. I need to further read in to this topic